# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < while deploying to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I was deploying a MEAN app on Heroku. But keep getting this Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <. In the console, it says it's in the index.js file that is in the public folder. It's from Traversy Media's MEAN APP tutorial series. 
I added the "start" : "node app.js" and node engine version in the package.json file. In my .gitignore, I only have node_modules/ . I cant really seem to find the problem here.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>True Heart</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

THis is the heroku build log

```html
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 353 bytes | 353.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  10.4.1
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 10.4.1...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 10.4.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.1.0
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        audited 1583 packages in 3.755s
remote:        found 2 high severity vulnerabilities
remote:        run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
remote: 
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote: 
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        audited 1583 packages in 3.408s
remote:        found 2 high severity vulnerabilities
remote:        run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
remote: 
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 22.9M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v13
remote:        https://mighty-eyrie-74454.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/mighty-eyrie-74454.git
   c34df49..29a6890  master -> master
```

Any help?

Comment: Use "heroku local" and devtools to run & debug localhost version. Then push to heroku and should just work

Comment: @robertrowntree I have the same problem. heroku local works but not when i deploy. I think this is due to a conflict with git... any idea?

Comment: @omar real test of local is 3 steps: 1. rm node_modules dir and children  2. run npm install  which should do a build  3. if not run a build   THEN  run 'heroku local'

Comment: the problem was a `.gitignore` file

Comment: it was left over from another repo and caused the deploy to be incomplete